# How to use variable declared inside function outside of it?

Tags: python, function, variables, tkinter

How do I use a variable that I declared inside a function outside one. Do I have to declare a function first and then use it?
Using `global` doesn't work, so what do I do?

I am using the variable inside a tkinter `Label` function, like so:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def a():
    b = "hello world"

a()
q = Label(root, textvariable=b).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

So that might be a part of the issue, but I'm still not sure.
The error message simply says the variable doesn't exist.

Comment: using `global` **absolutely works** but you *shouldn't do it that way*. But in any case, your exact situation is totally unclear. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: If `b` is a tkinter `StringVar` defined *outside the function*, then in a function like `a()` you don't need to declare it `global` because you simply set/change its value via `b.set("hello world")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before assigning a variable to a label which was inside a function, you need to call the function at least once to initiate the variable. Furthermore, to call a variable outside of your function you need to use the `global` function inside it.
I know it sounds confusing but the code down below will work:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def a():
  global b # making the variable a global variable to be able to call it out of the function
  b = "hello world"


a() #initiate the variable by calling the function
q = Label(root,text=b) 
q.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Tell me if this worked !

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are misusing `global`.

In order to change the scope of a variable to the global scope you need to do that in separate statement, as in:

```
def a:
    global b
    b = hello world

q = Label(textvariable=b).pack
```

for more examples please check:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp

With that said. Using global might not be the best code design choice to use. Scope helps keep things modular and organised.